# Навигация в Xamarin MvvMCross

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

Есть две ViewModel, first и second.
В первой по ShowViewModel вызываем вторую. Во второй, по нажатию на кнопку - вызываем Close(this)
В результате - приложение сворачивается, так как возможно закрываются все View.
Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужна навигация от MVVM Cross то необходимо в конструкторе объявить через CI (Constructor Injection) сервис IMvxNavigationService и дальше использовать его для навигации.

```
private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

public MyViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigation)
{
  _navigationService = navigationService;
}

...
_navigationService.Navigate<TViewModel>() // реализация TViewModel была задекларирована ранее через Dependency Injection
//ShowViewModel устаревшая функция.
...
```

Логика с Close(this) должна работать как положено и вернуть на первую ViewModel.
https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation

```
public class ViewModelOne : MvxViewModel
    {
        private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

        public ViewModelOne(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;

            Task.Run(async () => { await Navigate(); });
        }

        public ICommand ShowViewModelTwo => new MvxAsyncCommand(Navigate);

        /// <summary>
        /// Moves to ViewModel two
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Task</returns>
        private async Task Navigate()
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            await _navigationService.Navigate<ViewModelTwo>();
        }
    }
public class ViewModelTwo : MvxViewModel
    {
        private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

        public ViewModelTwo(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;

            Task.Run(async () => { await Return(); });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Closes this ViewModel and returns to previous
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Task</returns>
        private async Task Return()
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            await _navigationService.Close(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Все равно, работает так же.

Comment: @VladFinni посмотрите пример. Так ли у вас написано? это навигация работает. на ios/android платформах нативного кода.

Comment: Стояло свойство NoHistory.
Исправил.